# R creating multiple 2 by 2 tables from a data frame

Tags: r

Next question - I have created the following data frame in R

```
x <- as.integer(rnorm(n=1000, mean=10, sd=5))
y <- 1:1000
z <- sample (c(0,1),1000, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

# create variables df using x

for(i in 1:10){
df[paste0("col",i)] <- ifelse(df$x <i, 1, 0)
}

# create 2 by 2 tables of z against col1 to col 10

for(i in 1:10){
table[i]  <- table (df[paste0("col",i)], df$z)
}
```

I already received some excellent help to create variables in R using a for loop within a data frame.

However i am now struggling with using a similar for loop to create a two by two table  (last section of the code).

Can anybody tell where i am going wrong?

Thanks again as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with the code you have written.

First of all, the `table` data-object does not exist, so you cannot index-assign to it.

Secondly, you need to use "[[" when accessing a named item (otherwise you get a sublist).

Finally, if you make a list, which is really the most sensible type of storage for a series of table-objects, you need to use "[[" rather than "[" to extract an item (rather than a sublist).

I also took the liberty of renaming it to `tbl` so there would not be cognitive confusion about what was function and what was data.

```
 tbl<- list();
 
 for(i in 1:10){
    tbl[[i]]  <- table (df[[paste0("col",i)]], df$z) 
 }

 tbl[[1]]
   
      0   1
  0 488 473
  1  16  23
```

Comment: Thanks BondedDust that worked perfectly - am still really confused about R and indexing! Can i ask what is the purpose of the semi colon after list ()? And what does list () do ? Thanks again!

Comment: The semicolon is the newline or new command separator. Could have put in a linefeed. The list() just makes `tbl` an empty list .... with a name.